# double pointer and how to modify the pointer in the function

Tags: c, pointers, opencv, double-pointer

in this example from opencv, why didn't we create a simple variable img (instead of a pointer) and then use a simple pointer in the parameter of the function `cvReleaseImage` (whereas here, we will use a double pointer in the parameter because we're passing the address of the pointer : `&img`) :

```
IplImage* img = NULL; 
img = cvLoadImage(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
cvReleaseImage (&img);
```

?

Also, when we use a simple pointer in a function, we can change the pointed value by adding another `*` to the pointer :

for example :

```
function random(int* pointer, int* pointer2){
    *pointer = *pointer2 / 2;
}
```

so with a double pointer, should we do this? :

```
function random(int** doublepointer, int* pointer2){
    **doublepointer = *pointer2 / 2;
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple: `cvLoadImage()` as the name suggests, loads an entire image to memory (consider a 10MB file) and returns a `IplImage*` that says where the image data is located in memory.

This is incredibly useful, because if it returned an `IplImage` instead, our application would need to allocate another 10MB of memory, duplicating the data in the program's memory! So returning a pointer with the memory address of the data is actually a very smart design decision.

`cvReleaseImage()` receives a double pointer to reflect this design. If you download OpenCV v2.3 source code you can see it's implementation at `modules/core/src/array.cpp`:

```
2979 CV_IMPL void
2980 cvReleaseImage( IplImage ** image )
2981 {
2982     if( !image )
2983         CV_Error( CV_StsNullPtr, "" );
2984 
2985     if( *image )
2986     {
2987         IplImage* img = *image;
2988         *image = 0;
2989 
2990         cvReleaseData( img );
2991         cvReleaseImageHeader( &img );
2992     }
2993 }
```

It's clear that the actual release of memory resources is done by 2 other helper functions, which at some point will call `cvFree()` to free the memory.

The simplification of `cvReleaseImage()` shared by @Nikolai is correct, though.

**EDIT:** to answer your comment.

**Assigning a pointer to `0` will never deallocate the memory** that was reserved with `malloc()` / `new`, it just makes the pointer point to somewhere else, and in this case, nowhere! Let's understand what `cvReleaseImage (&img)` means. It all starts with:

```
IplImage* img = NULL;
```

A pointer declaration does the same thing as regular variable declaration: it allocates a certain amount of memory to store some data. A pointer declaration (in a 32bit arch) like  the one above allocates 4 bytes of memory to store the address of some other variable. In other words, the pointer itself consumes 4 bytes of memory within the function it was declared.

Calling `cvReleaseImage(&img)` passes the **address of the pointer** and not the address of the data it's pointing to (A-HA moment right here).

Now, let's analyse the rest of the code:

```
2985     if( *image ) // does the original pointer points somewhere?
2986     {
             // img copies the address of the data pointed by it's cousing image 
2987         IplImage* img = *image; 
             // and handles the deallocation procedure from now own using img.

             // By clearing the original pointer,
2988         *image = 0; 
             // OpenCV allows us to test for it's release 
             // after cvReleaseImage() executes. 

2989 
2990         cvReleaseData( img );

2991         cvReleaseImageHeader( &img );
2992     }
```

So doing `*image = 0;` is just standard procedure so later we can check for a sucessful deallocation like this:

```
cvReleaseImage (&img);
if (img != NULL)
{
  // OOPS! Something went wrong, memory was not released!
}
```

Comment: thanks karlphillip! it becomes more clear to me, in the code above, why do they create another pointer from `*image` to `*img`? and `*image = 0` removes the space in memory or does it remove the pointer itself? thanks

Comment: thanks karlphillip, i'm sorry i'm not sure to fully understand this : if `img` copies the address, what's the point to not continue using `*image`? also, thanks for the explanation about `image=0`

Comment: It's probably a code convention used by the development team, in case a function needs to forward a double pointer parameter ahead to some other helper function, which happens on `cvReleaseImageHeader(&img);`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the idea here is that `cvReleaseImage()` can do something like this:

```
void cvReleaseImage( IplImage** ppimg ) {
    /* ... */
    free( *ppimg );
    *ppimg = NULL;
}
```

i.e. release the memory and clean the original pointer.

Comment: thanks Nikolai : if we remove the pointer, shouldn't we also remove the object/the space in memory where the pointer points to?

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty typical in "release" or "free" functions to pass a pointer to a pointer so that the actual pointer (in this case img) that the user sees can be set to NULL and therefore not accidentally used after being deleted.

And yeah, you just double-dereference to change the data in the pointer-to-pointer, but I'd recommend using parentheses:

```
(*(*doublepointer)) = (*pointer)/2;
```

It just looks nicer I think.

Answer (score 1):

As to the first question: the size of the IplImage is likely not known until it is loaded, whereas the size of a "simple variable" would have to be known at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

The function cvLoadImage returns a pointer to IplImage so you cannot use a locally defined IplImage:

```
IplImage* cvLoadImage( const char* filename, int iscolor=CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR );
```

The cvReleaseImage requires the address of the pointer to the IplImage structure.  By doing this, they can set the pointer to a NULL value when the structure is deleted so that the deleted object cannot be used inadvertently.